# Adjust boxrule of algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e

I have this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[portuguese, ruled, linesnumbered, boxruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \SetAlgoLined
    \Entrada{Parâmetros}
    \Saida{$P_t$}
    \Inicio{
      $t \leftarrow$ GeraNovaPopulação(); \\
      Avalia($P_t$); \\
      \Enqto{\textbf{\textit{não}} CriterioParadaAtingido()}{
        $Q_t \leftarrow$ Variação($P_t$); \\
        Avalia($Q_t$); \\
        $P_{t + 1} \leftarrow$ Atualiza($Q_t$, $P_t$); \\
        $t \leftarrow t + 1$; \\
      }
    }
    \caption{Pseudocódigo de uma MOEA.\label{algo:moea-pseudocode}}
    \end{algorithm}}
\end{document}
```

And it produces the following output:

[image: Output from the code]

What I want to know if it is possible to decrease the width of the horizontal line, i.e, shrink it to the maximum.

EDIT:

The desired output, as posted in the comments by @Werner and mentioned by @marmot is:

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: @marmot Yes!

Sorry to not be totally clear!

Comment: So you want it to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GnJy.png)?

Comment: @Werner Yes! Exactly this way.

Comment: If you want a solution for this specific example, just wrap the `algorithm` into `\begin{minipage}{9cm}` and `\end{minipage}`. As for the general case, I have no clue. (One could probably use the `tikzmark` library to measure the length of the lines, but this will lead to a very convoluted proposal, at least when I try to spell it out.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`algorithm2e` package](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) completely manages its own floating mechanism and therefore doesn't have the regular handles or hooks one would associate with a float. As such, the simplest way to achieve what you're after is to wrap the `algorithm` inside a `center`ed `minipage` where you specify the block width:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[portuguese, ruled, linesnumbered, boxruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}{.725\linewidth}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
      \SetAlgoLined
      \Entrada{Parâmetros}
      \Saida{$P_t$}
      \Inicio{
        $t \leftarrow$ GeraNovaPopulação(); \\
        Avalia($P_t$); \\
        \Enqto{\textbf{\textit{não}} CriterioParadaAtingido()}{
          $Q_t \leftarrow$ Variação($P_t$); \\
          Avalia($Q_t$); \\
          $P_{t + 1} \leftarrow$ Atualiza($Q_t$, $P_t$); \\
          $t \leftarrow t + 1$; \\
        }
      }
      \caption{Pseudocódigo de uma MOEA.\label{algo:moea-pseudocode}}
    \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The value of `0.725\linewidth` is what you can tweak to suit your needs.

The above approach relies on the fact that your `algorithm` is set to stay `[H]`ere (where it's placed inside the text). If you want it to float but be constrained, you'll have to resort to something like this:

```
\begin{figure}[<float spec>]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{.725\linewidth}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
      % <your algorithm>
    \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```